# Adding dynamic elements to aui form in liferay

Tags: javascript, forms, liferay, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

How can we add dynamic aui form elements in liferay by using script or aui:script ?? If that is not possible, is there any alternate solution.

I have an aui form which has two sections. On clicking of a button, I want to add new sections to the form dynamically through javascript. I tried using document.createElement(), but by using that, we will be able to create only HTML dom elements. I want to create aui elements like aui:input, aui:select, etc

This is how my form is structured:

[image]

---

Assume that I have a button in second section. When I click that, I want to add one more aui:fieldset element to the aui:form as a child.

Comment: You can have 2 divs hidden (having your fields respectively) in your form and show them based on the button clicks through javascript, will that not work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> we will be able to create only HTML dom elements. I want to create aui elements like aui:input, aui:select, etc

Kindly understand `aui:input`, `aui:select` etc are JSP tags meaning they are server-side and are ultimately rendered into HTML elements by the container and that is what you see in the browser. Its just that those elements are rendered with some `<div>`s & `<span>`s (which are HTML elements!) and have their own css-class.

So on a click of a button if you want to a create another form element than you have to use either `document.createElement` or `document.innerHTML`. Javascript has nothing to do with server side so it can't generate or render `aui` tags, but you can create HTML elements and add to the form similar in style to the `aui` tags.

Here are some basic tutorials to get you started with Alloy UI javascript:

1. [Working with Elements and Events](https://www.liferay.com/web/nathan.cavanaugh/blog/-/blogs/alloyui-working-with-elements-and-events), you can scroll down to `Manipulating elements` heading.
2. [Alloy UI - working with Nodes](http://alloyui.com/examples/node/full/)
3. [Alloy UI Form builder](http://alloyui.com/examples/form-builder/), only works with Liferay 6.2.

**Liferay way of doing things**

Adding Addresses and Phonenumbers in Users and Organizations module (<kbd>Control Panel</kbd> → <kbd>Organization</kbd> → <kbd>Edit</kbd> → <kbd>Identification section</kbd> → <kbd>Addresses</kbd>), you can check the following JSPs:

1. [/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/users_admin/common/addresses.jsp](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/users_admin/common/addresses.jsp#L126)
2. [/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/users_admin/common/phone_numbers.jsp](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/users_admin/common/phone_numbers.jsp#L107)

---

**EDIT** <sub>(As per the OP's comment)</sub>

1. [Tutorial on Liferay Auto-fields](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/10/liferay-auto-fields.html).
2. [Source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/meeralferay/files/LiferayAutoFieldsPortlet/) of the tutorial.

---

A Short tutorial on auto-fields inspired by LiferaySavvy Link above :-)
<sub>As per the policy of stackoverflow and for the convenience of users</sub>

The explanation is given as code comments.

1. Javascript code to create dynamic fields:

   ```
   <aui:script use="liferay-auto-fields">
   new Liferay.AutoFields(
       {
           contentBox: '#phone-fields', // this is the container within which the fields would be added dynamically
           fieldIndexes: '<portlet:namespace />phonesIndexes' // this is the field which will store the values of the 
       }
   ).render();
   </aui:script>
   ```
2. JSP or HTML code to work with the javascript:

   ```
   <aui:form action="<%=editArticleActionURL%>" method="post" name="LiferayAutoFieldForm">
       <div id="phone-fields">
           <div class="lfr-form-row lfr-form-row-inline">
               <div class="row-fields">
                   <!--
                       Notice the zero at the end of the name & id of the input element "phoneNumber0".
                       When you add dynamic fields this would be incremented.
                   -->
                   <aui:input fieldParam='phoneNumber0' id='phoneNumber0' name="phoneNumber0" label="Phone Number" />
                   <aui:select id="phoneTypeId0" name="phoneTypeId0" label="Type">
                       <aui:option value="11006" label="Business"></aui:option>
                       <aui:option value="11007" label="Business Fax"></aui:option>
                       <aui:option value="11008" label="Mobile Phone"></aui:option>
                       <aui:option value="11009" label="Other"></aui:option>
                       <aui:option value="11011" label="Personal"></aui:option>
                   </aui:select>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       .... <!-- other input fields and submit buttons etc -->
   </aui:form>
   ```
3. Code for fetching the dynamic element's values in our controller:

   ```
   String phonesIndexesString = actionRequest.getParameter("phonesIndexes"); // do you remember: fieldIndexes: '<portlet:namespace />phonesIndexes'? :-)
   int[] phonesIndexes = StringUtil.split(phonesIndexesString, 0);

   for (int phonesIndex : phonesIndexes) {
       String number = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "phoneNumber" + phonesIndex);
       int typeId = ParamUtil.getInteger(actionRequest, "phoneTypeId" + phonesIndex);
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Prakash for pointing out. I will try it out using autofields

Comment: For others trying to achieve the same task, I followed this tutorial for creating dynamic form : liferaysavvy.com/2013/10/liferay-auto-fields.html

Answer (score 2):

Look at `aui:auto-fields` tag lib. 
Let see an example of it within phone managment in user account.

Comment: Thanks Daniele. I will try it out using auto-fields and update

Comment: Is there really a taglib as auto-field, can you point out the liferay code that is using such a taglib?

Comment: For others trying to achieve the same task, I followed this tutorial for creating dynamic form :

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/10/liferay-auto-fields.html